Hyperinflation of debt/taxes
I assume that if you owed a large amount of money (including back taxes) in say 1920s Germany, the hyperinflation they experienced made paying off the debt very easy.
Or did Germany (or other countries like Venezuela and Argentina today) do things like increase penalties and interest rates for back taxes, even old pre-inflation debt?
I could see it being as simple as those who owed large amounts simply paying it off, but I could also see a government insist upon payment in gold or silver or today in a currency like dollars -- citizens were not allowed to pay their debt in inflated local currency.
